# Ethernet not working on Raspberry Pi 2 (Model B+ or B) running latest version of Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, pi-2, ethernet-port, internet

Today I was in the office using the corporate ethernet there with my Raspberry Pi, and it was working very smoothly. I was even able to tinker with some SSH and VNC connections and use the browser, and `ifconfig` had a working IP that I was able to use.

I went home, however and plugged in another yellow ethernet cable and the link lights didn't even come on. There was no change in `ifconfig` output before and after the cable was plugged in.

Here's what I've tried:

- Countless changes to the "interfaces" file
- Rebooting the router (with 20-sec interval)
- Removing and plugging in and removing and... with the cable
- Rebooting the Pi 2 multiple times
- Using `sudo ifdown` and `sudo ifup` with the argument "eth0"
- and much more...

After spending an hour searching on forum websites, I believe the problem is the cable though I can assure that it works with laptops. The cable is a standard Ethernet cable, with one end hooked into a wall outlet and the other into the Raspberry Pi 2.

Is there anything else you can recommend to fix this?

Comment: If it works good with laptop, i don't see any reason why link shouldn't be up on Rpi. Are you sure it's locked in perfectly ?

Comment: Try `ifconfig -a` (the `-a` is significant) or `ip link`.

Comment: 1. There is absolutely no difference in the output I get from `ifconfig -a` and just `ifconfig`.

Comment: `ip link` just prints out some random words, with the capitalized ones being "UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT", "<NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>", "LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP", etc.

Comment: And lastly: if I ping my own router's IP address I get:

`connect: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Good news: I finally got my WiFi adapter to work, but I'm still going to keep this post open, as the retailers say you need a power hub to efficiently use the adapter, or else it may drastically reduce the life of your Pi. In other words, I still need Ethernet to work!

Comment: Take a **very close** look at your cable ends at which wire goes to which pin. You may be trying to connect things with a crossover cable. (Some adapters/switches have auto-detect and can handle a crossover cable, some don't...) A standard Ethernet cable should have the same color wires on the same pins for both ends. If the wire color->pin mapping is different, then you have a crossover cable. (OR just borrow the cable from work that you know is good to troubleshoot?)

Comment: @alphacharlie The presence of the ethernet hardware interface should be indicated regardless of whether it is connected or in use.

Comment: Edit in the output from `grep eth0 /var/log/syslog | tail` if any.

Comment: Goldilocks - True, But I'm not seeing where they said the hardware device is missing? (But they didn't post the exact output of **ip link** either... I interpreted their response to your request as- _it showed **eth0** with <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>_ which is consistent with an unplugged LAN cable.)  Did I miss a post?

Comment: Good point.  It is hard to diagnose problems like this without the proper information being provided.  That's up to the O.P.

Comment: If fails, go back to the last working version.  In your case, I'd go back to the office and test whether it's still working there or not.  If it does work there (and assuming you're using the same laptop for connecting to the Pi), there is a problem with either that yellow LAN cable, your router, or the router's settings.  If you cannot go back to the office, reinstall the Pi with a brand fresh image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Available network interfaces can be listed with `ip link` or `ifconfig -a` (without `-a`, ifconfig does not show interfaces which are in a "down" state; this state is not a problem, it just means the interface is not in use).  Note that as per the man page, `ifconfig` is *"obsolete!  For replacement check ip addr and ip link..."*.

The output from both is a list, although the details and presentation are different.  If the list only contains one entry, it is probably `lo`, the [local loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface).  This is a conceptual IP interface (not hardware) used by the system.

On Raspbian, the ethernet NIC should by default be `eth0`.  If it is not there, it indicates one of two problems:

- The kernel is missing the appropriate drivers.  If you are using a stock pi distro kernel, this is not the problem, unless perhaps you have moved or tinkered with `/lib/modules`.
- Broken hardware.

You could try `grep eth0 /var/log/syslog | tail` to see what the last thing said about the interface was.

Note that the presence of an available interface does not indicate it is connected to anything.

Comment: I've marked this answer as correct because it's very helpful and is full of good tips